# Instances in which a term initially coined to reject a theory later became the widely accepted term for that very theory after it became the consensus

Tags: terminology, cosmology

I'm looking for an instance other than that of the 'big bang' — a term coined by Fred Hoyle to reject the theory being referred to. The theory also later went on to become the consensus with the very same name.

Symbolically put:

**Person A coins Term X to reject Theory Y.**

**Over time, Theory Y becomes the consensus.**

**Term X, initially coined to reject Theory Y, becomes the most common name for the now-consensus Theory Y.**

Comment: Stepping outside of science and mathematics and into the world of art, "Claude Monet's Impression, Sunrise (Musée Marmottan Monet, Paris) exhibited in 1874, gave the Impressionist movement its name when the critic Louis Leroy accused it of being a sketch or “impression,” not a finished painting." https://www.metmuseum.org/toah/hd/imml/hd_imml.htm

Comment: Thank you, @DJohnson. I didn't know about it. Very interesting. :)

Comment: Apparently, [Hoyle denied](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Fred_Hoyle/MWKQhXo2eaIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA129&printsec=frontcover) that "Big Bang" was meant "to reject" the theory (although he did reject it), it was rather meant "to create a picture in the mind of the listener". The idea that it was an insult comes from Gamow.

Comment: @Conifold, yes. While it's true that he did not coin the term in a derogatory manner, he didn't say that the intent was purely **descriptive** either. He said that his choice of a striking term was to differentiate it from the (what he considered to be correct) steady state model. https://books.google.co.in/books?id=41XBXCJrPVwC&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=%22i+coined+it+to+be+striking%22+%22hoyle%22#v=onepage&q=%22i%20coined%20it%20to%20be%20striking%22%20%22hoyle%22&f=false

Comment: @Conifold If we take the original radio talk into consideration: as soon as he coins the term, he begins to criticize and prove wrong the theory (he called it a **hypothesis**) — even going as far as to call the earlier approaches futile in the long run. He, then, subsequently introduces his own hypothesis. https://www.joh.cam.ac.uk/library/special_collections/hoyle/exhibition/radio/

Comment: Do "negative" and "imaginary" numbers count? Both were coined to deny them existence